# Yahoo email alignment issue; style="table-layout: fixed;" breaking non resposive emails on mobile

Tags: html-email

I'm having a problem centring emails in the yahoo web client, I’ve searched around and have only come up with:

`style="table-layout: fixed;"`

Which works fine for desktop however it breaks the layout in non-responsive emails on mobile; making the pinch and zoom fail on windows mobile and collapsing the background on the Iphone client, my colleagues have come up with a fix involving a TD and a huge amount of   which works however it adds space either to the top or bottom of the email.

I'm wondering if anyone has any idea if we can expand on the table-layout fix so it will work with mobile or if there is something else I am missing entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue. The solution I found is to put ' align="center" ' inside the overall .

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue but had to make sure I added `width="100%"` and `align="center"` within the out most table you have.

This works on IE, Firefox, and Chrome. But I have not found a solution in Safari? It also, wipes out any `bgcolor` I have for the email also.

Does anyone have suggestions for this?